# Pagination issue with real time data in Druid Scan query

Tags: druid

I have gone through following Druid Scan query documentation
https://druid.apache.org/docs/0.20.0/querying/scan-query.html . I didn't understand the part when it says. "note that if the underlying datasource is modified in between page fetches in ways that affect overall query results, then the different pages will not necessarily align with each other."

In my case data is added to Druid in real time which means suppose I queried for last one hour data(4-5PM), it might possible that earlier we had 40 records for that query but during the query we received 10 new records. My assumption is that all new records should get added post 40th record and it should not impact the current running paging offset. Please help me how realtime ingestion of data can impact the Druid pagination and what could be the possible fix for that.

> offset    : Together, "limit" and "offset" can be used to implement
> pagination.
> However, note that if the underlying datasource is modified in between page fetches in ways that affect overall query results, then
> the different pages will not necessarily align with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs describe that the offset/limit are application side values. From the database perspective, it is running the whole query again with every request and just returning the rows between `offset` and `offset + limit`.

So, if ordered by `__time desc`, new rows will appear at the top of the results and therefore shift the content of the pagination.
If sorted `__time asc`, and no out of time order rows are ingested between calls, then the pagination should be constant and new rows appear at the end.

Also remember that it is a good practice to limit the overall timeframe that you are querying.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response here. Can you please also help on follow up question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71088282/how-to-sort-data-based-on-one-of-the-timestamp-field-in-druid-scan-query 
Thanks again!!!