# How to sort data based on one of the timestamp field in Druid Scan Query

Tags: druid

I'm using Druid scan query with ordering param "ascending". It is returning data based on configured timestamp field called serverReceiveTime. I wanted to sort my data on one of the other timestamp field(streamingSegmentStartTime). As per Scan query [documentation](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/scan-query.html), there is no such sort argument we can pass.

```
ScanDruidQuery.builder()
                .dataSource(route.getDataSource())
                .intervals(IntervalParser.getIntervals(getSessionsQuery.getStartTime(), getSessionsQuery.getEndTime()))
                .filter(filterTranslator.translate(getSessionsQuery.getFilter()))
                .order(DRUID_DATA_SORT_ORDER)
                .columns(columnList)
                .context(new DruidQueryContext(genericQuery.getRequestId()))
                .limit(getSessionsQuery.getResultSize())
                .offset(NumberUtils.toInt(getSessionsQuery.getNextToken(), 0))
                .build();
```

Please let me know if there is any way to sort this data based on streamingSegmentStartTime at Druid end

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your query is doing, so this might not help, but you can sort by other columns if you use a group by query.

Take a look at the `sortByDimsFirst` query context property of the Group By query here: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/groupbyquery.html#groupby-v2-configurations

If you set the first dimension of the DimensionSpec to the `streamingSegmentStartTime` and use `sortByDimsFirst` set to True, I think you can achieve what you want.